# Panel size does not expand in a frame with a menu

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython, sizer

I've created a frame with a menu bar in wxpython and set the main sizer as a child of the frame itself, but the frame's panel stays in a fixed size after resizing the frame. When removing the menu bar and setting the main sizer to the panel itself resizing works perfectly, but with the menu added to the frame setting the main sizer to the panel doesn't work.

tl;dr - the panel size for this code stays fixed. How do I make it resizable?

```
import wx

class Mainframe(wx.Frame):
def __init__(self,parent,title):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,title=title,size=(650,450))
    self.Main_Panel = wx.Panel(self,id=wx.ID_ANY)

    #################################################################
    ### Template menubar menubar
    #################################################################
    Menubar = wx.MenuBar()
    Filemenu = wx.Menu()
    Debugmenu = wx.Menu()

    self.Menu_Open_File = Filemenu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN,"Open","Open an nrix file to edit")
    self.Menu_SaveAs_File = Filemenu.Append(wx.ID_SAVEAS,"Save as","Normal saving will be incorporated later")
    Filemenu.AppendSeparator()
    self.Menu_About_Dialog = Filemenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT,"About","Information about the program and changelog")
    self.Debug_State_Switch = Debugmenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY,"Debug on","Turn on debug mode",wx.ITEM_CHECK)

    Menubar.Append(Filemenu,"File")
    Menubar.Append(Debugmenu,"Debug")
    self.SetMenuBar(Menubar)
    #################################################################
    ### Frame objects
    #################################################################
    Left_Static_text = wx.StaticText(self.Main_Panel,wx.ID_ANY,style=wx.ALIGN_LEFT)
    Left_Static_text.SetFont(wx.Font(16,wx.ROMAN,wx.NORMAL,wx.FONTWEIGHT_NORMAL))
    Left_Static_text.SetLabel("Exploitable text")

    Left_Text_Control = wx.TextCtrl(self.Main_Panel,wx.ID_ANY,value="Exploitable")

    Buttons = []
    for i in range(4):
        Buttons.append(wx.Button(self.Main_Panel,label=str(i + 1),size=(50,50)))
    #################################################################
    ### Frame sizers
    #################################################################
    Grid_Sizer = wx.GridSizer(2,2,15,15)
    Ver_Wrapper = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    Left_Sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    Whole_Sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
    #################################################################
    ### Attaching sizers
    #################################################################
    for i in range(4):
        Grid_Sizer.Add(Buttons[i],0,wx.EXPAND)

    Ver_Wrapper.Add((0,0),proportion=1,flag=wx.EXPAND)
    Ver_Wrapper.Add(Grid_Sizer,proportion=0,flag=wx.CENTER)
    Ver_Wrapper.Add((0,0),proportion=1,flag=wx.EXPAND)

    Left_Sizer.Add((0,0),proportion=1,flag=wx.EXPAND)
    Left_Sizer.Add(Left_Static_text,proportion=0,flag=wx.CENTER)
    Left_Sizer.Add(Left_Text_Control,proportion=0,flag=wx.CENTER)
    Left_Sizer.Add((0,0),proportion=1,flag=wx.EXPAND)

    Whole_Sizer.Add(Left_Sizer,proportion=1,flag=wx.EXPAND)
    Whole_Sizer.Add(Ver_Wrapper,proportion=3,flag=wx.EXPAND)

    # self.Main_Panel.SetSizer(Whole_Sizer) <- THIS WORKS WITHOUT A MENU
    self.SetSizer(Whole_Sizer)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = Mainframe(None,"Menu UI")
frame.Show(True)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Doing `self.Main_Panel.SetSizer(Whole_Sizer)` works for me in Xubuntu 16.04 with wxPython 3.0.2.0 and Python 2.7. Not sure why this isn't working for you. I will say that the `self.SetSizer(Whole_Sizer)` just makes the window completely empty on my machine.

Comment: I tried it in Windows 7 and 10, both times with Python 2.7 . Specifically setting the sizer for self.Main_Panel causes all widgets to coalesce into the top left corner.

Comment: Tried in Linux mint 18 and it works there as well. Perhaps this I think this is a problem with the windows forms. Any idea how to go around it?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is just a small glitch. When `Whole_Sizer` is attributed to `Main_Panel` in Windows, all of the widgets are positioned in the upper left corner. Once I started messing with the window size by dragging the window corner around the whole thing solved itself. Now I just feel stupid.

Comment: You can call `Layout` on the sizer before showing the frame and that will probably fix the issue